# On Windows, how do I make it so that any connection to "imap.gmail.com" & "smtp.gmail.com" use a specific network interface?

Tags: networking, cmd.exe, routing, imap, smtp

After many years of searching, asking and hoping, I've now given up 100% on ever being able to specify this in PHP for imap_open() and PHPMailer. They simply don't feature this, nor the ability to set a SOCKS server. So I must do it in my OS, or something "outside" of PHP at least.

On Windows 10, how would I make it so that any network connection to "imap.gmail.com" and "smtp.gmail.com" uses the network interface "123.123.123.123" instead of the "default route"?

Ideally, I want this as a single command line command, so that I can automate/integrate it and never have to think about it for future installations. Plus points if there is a command to easily reverse/clear these rules as well.

Answer (score 0):

Both "imap.gmail.com" and "smtp.gmail.com" are routed to the IP address of
`74.125.140.108` (there is no guarantee that this won't change in the future).

You should use the
[route command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/route_ws2008)
to route this IP address through the gateway from the specified network adapter.

If the other adapter is the default gateway (IP `0.0.0.0`) and you don't want to
disable this by ensuring that it doesn't service the IP of `74.125.140.108`,
then give the route you create a metric that is lower than that of the default
route `0.0.0.0` (lower metric means higher priority).
Normally the metric `1` is not used, so it is easy to make your route have the
highest priority.

Example: To add such a route with the gateway of `192.168.12.1` :

```
route add 74.125.140.108 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.12.1 1
```

Under some conditions, you might need to add above the `ip` parameter for
forcing the network interface. See the documentation for details.